# Удаление ссылок с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$string = 'Получаю только https://test.com/list?list=LLYRGq_jXSq6b3_BA текст а не ссылки http://veg.net/?pomidor=ogurec%131%ea%f в тексте. И все равно не то';
$pattern = '/https?.*\s/u';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "" ,$string);
```

В общем в данной маске пытаюсь выделить ссылки от http(s) до первого следующего пробела, но, к сожалению, слишком много хапает выборка. Как собственно захватить только ссылку и первый после неё пробел?

Answer (score 1):

> сожалению, слишком много хапает выборка.

Чтобы решить *эту* проблему, после звездочки надо поставить знак вопроса. Это ограничит жадность символьного класса и он будет искать до первого пробела, а не до последнего.

Но чтобы сделать более-менее универсальное решение,

```
'~(ftp|http)s?://\S+~ui';
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующую регулярку, обычно использую её для URL:

```
(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?
```

Тогда ваш код:

```
$string = 'Получаю только https://test.com/list?list=LLYRGq_jXSq6b3_BA текст а не ссылки http://veg.net/?pomidor=ogurec%131%ea%f в тексте. И все равно не то';
$pattern = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "" ,$string);
```

Выведет следующее:

> Получаю только  текст а не ссылки  в тексте. И все равно не то

Comment: устарело лет на 10

Comment: Опять идиоты-доброхоты поощряют говнокод. может хватит уже?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй $pattern = " https://\S*\s "[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для Вашей задачи достаточно этого:

```
[a-z]+[:.].*?(?=\s)
```

Результат:

```
Match 1
Full match  15-59   `https://test.com/list?list=LLYRGq_jXSq6b3_BA`
Match 2
Full match  78-121  `http://www.veg.net/?pomidor=ogurec%131%ea%f`
```

Comment: а если ссылка стоит в конце строки? Ну то есть пробела после неё нет

Comment: Тогда не выйдет. Вы же ставили задачу "до первого следующего пробела".

Comment: @Wayer ну так у тебя то же самое. Что за манера, сначала написать один вопрос, потом предъявлять претензии, что тебе не ответили на другой?

Comment: @Ипатьев я просто уточнил, я менял своего основного вопроса.